# ListView with CheckDelegate items not keeping Checked Checkboxes when scrolling

Tags: python, listview, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

Holla, so I have this simple script that displays 100 elements in a GUI and each element has a checkbox, I can check the boxes and they do remain checked for a while, but if I scroll up or down until they get out of view they will reseted(sometimes only the first element will be checked).
Now I know that in ListView the elements are displayed once they come into view, and I've tried multiple things like Increasing the ListView Height , the ContentHeight, but nothing works.
This issues is the same for example RadioDelegate
Main.py file:

```
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QUrl,QTimer
import sys
app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine('main.qml')
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

main.qml :

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3



ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 550
    title: qsTr("Ttile")

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        ListView {
            id: listView
            objectName : "lvob"
            model: 100
            delegate: CheckDelegate {
                text: modelData
            }
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
        }
    }

}
```

Video Explanation : [Click Me](https://gfycat.com/TastyVibrantBrownbear)

What am I doing wrong? 
**Update**: after some more researching I found that I have to Store the checked items in an array,since I'm very new to python/qml how could I do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the problem is analyzed it is observed that if you move the list a bit and return to the initial position, the changes will keep the values ​​correctly, and when you move a lot as in your case, the changes are lost.

#### why it happens?

This phenomenon is caused because to improve efficiency ListView has a property called [`cacheBuffer`](http://%20https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qml-qtquick-listview.html#cacheBuffer-prop) that keeps some items persistent.

Then, the solution is to save the changes in some other element that stores the data persistently as a [`ListModel`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html):

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 550
    title: qsTr("Ttile")

    ListModel {
        id: checkmodel
        Component.onCompleted: {
            for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                checkmodel.append({"name": i, "value": false})
            }
        }

    }
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        ListView {
            id: listView
            objectName : "lvob"
            model: checkmodel
            delegate: CheckDelegate {
                text: name
                checked: value
                onCheckStateChanged: checkmodel.setProperty(index ,"value", checked)
            }
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
        }
    }
}
```

Other possible containers may be using other [`model`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qml-qtquick-listview.html#model-prop)s:

> **model : model**
>
> This property holds the model providing data for the list.
>
> The model provides the set of data that is used to create the items in
>   the view. Models can be created directly in QML using **ListModel**,
>   **XmlListModel** or **VisualItemModel**, or provided by C++ model classes. If a C++ model class is used, it must be a subclass of **QAbstractItemModel** or a simple list.
>
> See also Data Models.